# Creating kafka stream API for JSON's

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

i am trying to write a kafka stream code for converting JSON array to JSON elements...since i am new to kafka stream can any one help me out writing the code.. like what should be there in kstream and ktable..
and my stream of input ll be in the following format

```
[
 {"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359126933+05:30","data":0,"unit":""},
 {"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359175426+05:30","data":1,"unit":""}
]

[
 {"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359126933+05:30","data":2,"unit":""},
 {"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359175426+05:30","data":3,"unit":""}
]
```

and my output must be in the form

```
{"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359126933+05:30","data":0,"unit":""}
{"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359175426+05:30","data":1,"unit":""}
{"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359126933+05:30","data":2,"unit":""}
{"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:44:09.359175426+05:30","data":3,"unit":""}
```

can anyone help me out in writing the code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Kafka Streams, you can use a `flatMap()`. Something like

```java
// using new 1.0 API
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
builer.stream("topic").flatMap(...).to("output-topic");
```

Check out the examples and docs for more details:

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/index.html
- https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

Comment: so if i use flat map can i able to convert Json arrays to Json objects , as i have shown above in my ques?

Comment: And what should be my <key and value> in KStreams?? like what data types i need to specify for that..? Thanks a lot if u help me out in doing this.. i am stuck at this point...

Comment: Yes. You convert within flatMap. For you input stream, <key,value> types must match the types you use in your input topic. For output type, you can choose whatever type you want to write as a result type.

Comment: my input will be in the form Json Araays so what can be my key value pair? and my output should be Json objects...And in flatmap should i use split or what can i use for that?

Comment: If you don't use the key it can be `null` and you can just use `byte[]` a key type. And please read a JSON tutorial if you don't know how to split a JSON array...

Comment: can i use flatmapvalues instead of flatmap?

Answer (score -2):

in Python...

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer('topicName')
for message in consumer:
  print(message)
```

specify bootstrap_servers parameter in KafkaConsumer.

For Java look [cloudkarafka](https://www.cloudkarafka.com/docs-java.html), really good:

```
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));
while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
        System.out.printf("msg = %s\n", record.value());
    }
}
```

Comment: i need that in java..if u know can u help  me?

Comment: Done, is better in Scala in my Opinion ;)

Comment: The question was about Kafka Streams API -- not plain Kafka Consumer.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax  : how to do this string conversion to json value and send to another topic? do you have an example?